# Is it grammatically correct to start this phrase with "how"?

Tags: grammar

"How closely our interests align may surprise you."

Is it grammatically correct to start this phrase with "how"? If not, what rule makes that so?  Is there a better way to say this?  Thanks for any input!

Comment: What are you asking? Define *phrase* in this case. The sentence you give *doesn't* start with *how*; it starts with *if so*. Or by *phrase* are you referring to the portion of the sentence that starts with *how* and ends with *you*? (You might want to put the phrase you mean in bold or something.) Also, are you questioning it in conjunction with *if so* specifically? If not, why not just drop those two words and start the sentence with *how*?

Comment: Good idea on emboldening the part after the comma - at the time I couldn't think of an elegant way to refer to it.  The validity of the phrase in question has nothing to do with it being preceded by "If so", so I'll drop it as to not confuse anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence itself is grammatically correct. In this use, *how* is an adverb, not a conjunction, describing the degree of closeness, and it is perfectly acceptable to begin a phrase with an adverb. For example: Even camels need to drink.